# Как растянуть flowplayer на весь экран?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как растянуть flowplayer на весь экран. Благодарю

```
<html>        
    <body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <div>
            <object  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" classid="clsid:D27AB7DE-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
                <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
                <param name="movie" value="http://streams2.renet.ru/flowplayer-3.2.5-0.swf" />
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
                <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":{"live":true,"autoPlay":true,"provider":"rtmp","url":"cam65-1","bufferLength":10, "connectionArgs": ["eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMjMsInNlc3Npb25faWQiOjh9--3f235e33847a2ba4d41aae375b63cc3f5c4166b5"]},"plugins":{"controls":{"url":"http://streams2.renet.ru/flowplayer.controls-3.2.3.swf","time":false,"scrubber":false,"stop":true,"play":false},"rtmp":{"url":"http://streams2.renet.ru/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf","netConnectionUrl":"rtmp://streams3.renet.ru:1935/live"}}}' /> 
                <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
                       src="http://streams2.renet.ru/flowplayer-3.2.5-0.swf" 
                       bgcolor="#000000" 
                       allowscriptaccess="always" 
                       allowfullscreen="true" 
                       flashvars='config={"clip":{"live":true,"autoPlay":true,"provider":"rtmp","url":"cam65-1","bufferLength":10, "connectionArgs": ["eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMjMsInNlc3Npb25faWQiOjh9--3f235e33847a2ba4d41aae375b63cc3f5c4166b5"]},"plugins":{"controls":{"url":"http://streams2.renet.ru/flowplayer.controls-3.2.3.swf","time":false,"scrubber":false,"stop":true,"play":false},"rtmp":{"url":"http://streams2.renet.ru/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf","netConnectionUrl":"rtmp://streams3.renet.ru:1935/live"}}}'
                />
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот решение задачи: нужно прописать размер объекта в самом object'е

```
<html>        
    <body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <div>
            <object  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" classid="clsid:D27AB7DE-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
                <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
                <param name="movie" value="http://streams2.renet.ru/flowplayer-3.2.5-0.swf" />
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
                <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":{"live":true,"autoPlay":true,"provider":"rtmp","url":"cam65-1","bufferLength":10, "connectionArgs": ["eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMjMsInNlc3Npb25faWQiOjh9--3f235e33847a2ba4d41aae375b63cc3f5c4166b5"]},"plugins":{"controls":{"url":"http://streams2.renet.ru/flowplayer.controls-3.2.3.swf","time":false,"scrubber":false,"stop":true,"play":false},"rtmp":{"url":"http://streams2.renet.ru/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf","netConnectionUrl":"rtmp://streams3.renet.ru:1935/live"}}}' /> 
                <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
                       src="http://streams2.renet.ru/flowplayer-3.2.5-0.swf" 
                       style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0;"
                       bgcolor="#000000" 
                       allowscriptaccess="always" 
                       allowfullscreen="true" 
                       flashvars='config={"clip":{"live":true,"autoPlay":true,"provider":"rtmp","url":"cam65-1","bufferLength":10, "connectionArgs": ["eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMjMsInNlc3Npb25faWQiOjh9--3f235e33847a2ba4d41aae375b63cc3f5c4166b5"]},"plugins":{"controls":{"url":"http://streams2.renet.ru/flowplayer.controls-3.2.3.swf","time":false,"scrubber":false,"stop":true,"play":false},"rtmp":{"url":"http://streams2.renet.ru/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf","netConnectionUrl":"rtmp://streams3.renet.ru:1935/live"}}}'
                />
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```